# Minimum and Maximum for edit text with decrementing and incrementing buttons in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-button

Hello am having a linear layout which is the parent layout and which which is holding an Edit text and a decrementing button before the edit text and and incrementing button after the edit text. The idea is when the decrementing button is clicked the number value in the edit text reduces by one and when the incrementing button is clicked the number value in the edit text increases by one. What i would love is to set the maximum number and minimum number of the edit text such that when that maximum is reached it displays a toast showing that the maximum number has been reached and when the minimum is also reached a toast is displayed showing the that the minimum number.

Here is my XML layout holding the buttons and the edit text

```
          <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_decrement"
                        style="@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:theme="@style/ButtonsTheme"
                        app:icon="@drawable/ic_remove_icon" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/item_quantity_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:text="1" />

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_increment"
                        style="@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.IconOnly"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:theme="@style/ButtonsTheme"
                        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_icon" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

Setting on click listeneres to the buttons

```
        btnDecrement.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnIncrement.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Switching cases for when the button is clicked

```
            case R.id.btn_decrement:
                decreaseQuantity();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_increment:
                increaseQuantity();
                break;
```

Methods for incrementing and decrementing the values in the edit text

```
 public void increaseQuantity() {
        display(Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString()) + 1);
    }

    public void decreaseQuantity() {
        display(Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString()) - 1);
    }

    private void display(int number) {
        etQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    }
```

etQuantity is the Edit text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add check logic in click listener.

```
        case R.id.btn_decrement:
            if (Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString()) + 1 < maximum) {
               decreaseQuantity();
            } else {
              // make toast.
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_increment:
            if (Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString()) - 1 > minimum) {
               increaseQuantity();
            } else {
              // make toast.
            }

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in Increment and decrement functions.

```
public void increaseQuantity() {
         If(etQuantity.getText().toString() == MAXVAL) 
             // Add code for displaying toast
        else
        display(Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString()) + 1);
    }
public void decreaseQuantity() {
         If(etQuantity.getText().toString() == MINVAL) 
             // Add code for displaying toast
        else
        display(Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString()) + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks nice implementation i appreciate